# Do work iptables across all users at the same time?

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, 17.10, iptables, firewall

I'm running Lubuntu 17.10 and I have two accounts; `lightning` and `scholar`. When logged into the desktop as `scholar` I want to block traffic to-and-from `https://www.facebook.com/` on `scholar`, even while logged in via terminal as `lightning` (i.e: using `su lightning` and launching firefox under `lightning`)

Comment: iptables is a system-wide process, no per-user configuration exists.

Comment: you could achieve what you want by adding `127.0.0.1 facebook.com` to `/etc/hosts` file; using a script (or command) adding this entry to the file when you want facebook.com to be disabled, and removing the entry when you want to allow access again.... (ie. script to toggle it into/out of file, or just reverse its current state).  you could also have two /etc/hosts (one with it, one without); and just `cp -p` them over the /etc/hosts as required...  It'll mean facebook.com traffic is routed to localhost which can't respond (*unless you ...*).  You could have this script run when you login..

Comment: That sounds extremely finnicky, and if I wanted to manage multiple sites (i.e site A; allow, site B; deny), it would become very difficult very fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, according to `waltinator`, that iptables affects every user on the system at once.

For those of you looking for a GUI, I recommend going [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111/gui-for-iptables)